# Setting combobox default value using SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf

Why is that whenever I try to put SlectedIndex to 0, it always remains -1 ?

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _dropDownValues = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> DropDownValues
    {
        get { return _dropDownValues; }
        set { _dropDownValues = value; }
    }

    private string _selectedValue;
    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return _selectedValue; }
        set { _selectedValue = value; }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        DropDownValues.Add("item1");
        DropDownValues.Add("item2");
        DropDownValues.Add("item3");
        DropDownValues.Add("item4");
        DropDownValues.Add("item5");
        DropDownValues.Add("item6");

        if (combotest.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            combotest.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10">
        <ComboBox Name="combotest"
            Margin="0 0 0 5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DropDownValues}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"        
            Width="150"/>     
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but you havent set the `SelectedValuePath` in your XAML. Also once you set `SelectedValuePath`, you only need to set the default `SelectedValue` (same as the first item's value property from your items source) and there is no need for your `SelectedIndex` code.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: what should I select SelectedValuePath to ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of setting the index.

```
string s = DropDownValues[0];
SelectedItem = s;
```

Comment: FYI the method above leans more towards the MVVM pattern which I promote over doing thing in code behind of the window / user control whenever possible.